# Sql server security principles

Tags: sql-server, security

If I have a website that uses a sa account for SQL authentication, this will be very bad idea, because with any SQL injection attempt, everyone can destroy database or steal credit cards.

Is there another risk rather than SQL injection?

What will be the user when you use Windows authentication?

Thank you for your time

Comment: "If I have a website that uses a sa account for SQL authentication" - if that's the case, someone needs firing.... preferably out of a cannon

Comment: "If I leave the button to launch our nukes and the passcodes to fire them out on the street for anyone to pick up, is there any other risk besides armageddon?" Isn't the threat of SQL Injection bad enough? I understand you are learning, but SQL Injection should be consider a severe risk.

Comment: Btw, how the website handles security is different based on the technology used to build the site and web server. For example, IIS6 and ASP Classic have a different setup for Windows Authentication than say .NET on either IIS6 or IIS7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the SA account is bad, really bad but I would say that using the SA account does not make you for likely to get “hacked” however if they do then you are in for a world of pain as they will have the top level of access and be able to really mess things up!

Also if the developer is stupid enough to think that using SA is a good security model then you can have a good bet that other areas of his/her security thinking will be equally bad. In short get it changed and start looking through the code for the classic rookie SQL mistakes